# Trying to assign each letter the user inputs with an expression, then print the word and the added total of that word

Tags: python

I'm looking for a quick solution to calculating multiple variables with expressions and then adding the totals of those expressions together. I know Adding `if` cases to every possible combination is not the way to go.

```
h = 8 * 6
e = 5 * 6
l = 12 * 6
o = 15 * 6

example: type in any word: hello
>>> hello: 312
```

1. Assign each alphabet letter variable its own alphabet string equivalent. E.g. `a = 'a'`
2. While True, ask the user to enter any word.
3. If a letter is in the word, assign each letter with an expression. E.g. `a = 1 * 6`

After that I'm not sure how I can easily handle any combination of letters the user inputs to add the totals afterward.

Comment: use a `dict`...

Comment: Unspecified in your question, but it looks like you might be interested in using `ord()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your letters and values are in a dictionary you can easily lookup the value as you loop over the letters.

For example:

```
letter_values = {
  'h': 8 * 6,
  'e': 5 * 6,
  'l': 12 * 6,
  'o': 15 * 6
}

letter_values['h'] # 48

# use get() to return zero if not found

letter_values.get('h', 0) # 48
letter_values.get('&', 0) # 0
```

With this you can make a comprehension to loop over the letters in you word and take the sum of the result:

```
# for each letter get the value (or 0) and sum them:
sum(letter_values.get(letter, 0) for letter in str)

# result 312
```

Comment: Get does not return zero unless you tell it to. If returns None.

Comment: Thanks @MadPhysicist – had it in the second example just forgot it in the first.